# .get() IE only issue

Tags: jquery

I am fetching some value from another page using jQuery .get() like this

```
<input size="30" id="abc" value="" type="text" readonly="readonly">
<input size="30" id="pqr" value="" type="text" readonly="readonly">    

$.get('clientarea.php?', function(data) {
var newVal = $('input[name=customfield[1]]', data).val();
$('#abc').val(newVal);
var newVal = $('input[name=customfield[2]]', data).val();
$('#pqr').val(newVal);
});
```

This script works fine in all browser except IE

What is wrong with this script ? Is there any issue with selecting name attr with jQuery in IE ?

Need your Help.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet explorer has problems sometimes to realize an object is an XML object.
I've successfully used the following workaround and it works fine:

http://rationalogic.com/development/jquery-ajax-and-internet-explorer/